# Unspecified bytes in SSL serverhello message

Tags: ssl, handshake

During SSL 3.0 handshaking server responses with the following serverhello message

```
16 03 00 00 51 02 00
00 4d 03 00 4f a1 c1
eb e3 fb 00 a9 c8 25
25 48 6f 89 27 ec bb
80 f3 8c 5d db f7 6c
94 56 d8 34 7a b5 9d
02 20 54 ab 20 ea 05
a6 38 6f ee 55 40 ae
af e2 5d ae 2a 4d c1
c6 f4 09 a7 08 b1 c5
49 39 87 82 d3 f7 00
39 00 00 05 ff 01 00
01 00
```

I understand this response as follows:

```
Content-type: 22 (Handshake protocol)
Version: 3.0
Length: a1 (81 bytes)

Content-type: 02 (ServerHello)
Length: 4d (77 bytes)
Version: 3.0
Random: 4f a1 c1 eb e3 fb 00 a9
        c8 25 25 48 6f 89 27 ec
        bb 80 f3 8c 5d db f7 6c
        94 56 d8 34 7a b5 9d 02
SessionID Length: 20 (32 bytes)
SessionID: 54 ab 20 ea 05 a6 38 6f
           ee 55 40 ae af e2 5d ae
           2a 4d c1 c6 f4 09 a7 08
           b1 c5 49 39 87 82 d3 f7
Cipher Suite: 00 39
Compression method: 00
```

But i can't understand how the last 7 bytes should be interpreted: 00 05 ff 01 00 01 00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the `renegotiation_info` extension, as defined in [RFC 5746](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.2):

> ```
> o  If this is the initial handshake for a connection, then the
>    "renegotiated_connection" field is of zero length in both the
>    ClientHello and the ServerHello.  Thus, the entire encoding of the
>    extension is ff 01 00 01 00.  The first two octets represent the
>    extension type, the third and fourth octets the length of the
>    extension itself, and the final octet the zero length byte for the
>    "renegotiated_connection" field.
> ```

Comment: Oh, thanks. Could you please specify the meaning of the first 00 byte that precedes 05 (renegotiated_connection length)?

Comment: `00 05` is the length of the [`Extension server_hello_extension_list<0..2^16-1>` list](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4366#section-2.2) (see [XDR notation](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4506#section-4.13)), on 2 bytes, since up to `2^16-1`.

Comment: The extensions spec is now merged into the TLS 1.2 specification, if you prefer to read everything in the same document.